# Python Selenium ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am using the Python (3.9) Selenium module (with latest geckodriver 0.29.1) on Windows.

When I run this script

```
from selenium import webdriver

firefox_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=firefox_profile)

print("Going into loop")

try:
    while True:
        pass
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Caught exception")
finally:
    print("Finally block")
    driver.get("https://google.com")

print("Got out of loop")
```

I get this error: (I am pressing Ctrl+C at ^C)

```
PS D:\Users\maart\PycharmProjects\testWeb> python3.9 .\test.py
Going into loop
^C
Caught exception
Finally block
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\maart\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "C:\Users\maart\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 84, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\maart\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 74, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\maart\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\maart\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\http\client.py", line 1253, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\http\client.py", line 1299, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\http\client.py", line 1248, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\http\client.py", line 1008, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\http\client.py", line 948, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\maart\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 187, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\maart\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 171, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000020FD45F98E0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\maart\PycharmProjects\testWeb\test.py", line 15, in <module>
    driver.get("https://google.com")
  File "C:\Users\maart\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "C:\Users\maart\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 319, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "C:\Users\maart\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 374, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "C:\Users\maart\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 397, in _request
    resp = self._conn.request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Users\maart\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\urllib3\request.py", line 79, in request
    return self.request_encode_body(
  File "C:\Users\maart\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\urllib3\request.py", line 171, in request_encode_body
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Users\maart\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 336, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\maart\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 754, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\maart\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 754, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\maart\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 754, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\maart\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 726, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\maart\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 439, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=52355): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/cc42916d-a399-45b8-90a0-a53f435e5d51/url (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000020FD45F98E0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))
```

Why is this happening? I made this special case because I want to make a program where you can get out of an infinite loop by pressing Ctrl + C, and then I want to call driver.quit(). That results in exactly the same error.

Comment: What is `^C` in console  ?

Comment: Ctrl + C sends an Interrupt Signal to a running program, and in python this signal throws a KeyboardInterrupt

Comment: Why would one do that ?

Comment: Well I want to use a selenium program that loops, until I want to stop it. You would normally stop a python program by pressing ctrl + c. This is the only way I know to stop the program

Comment: is it working with another driver like chrome?